# Python Pandas: Take Rows in my Column and categorize it as 1 Row?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

So my DF has columns: Agency | Base Pay | job_title | ... etc.

Now for my column: **job_title**, there are many different job titles registered.

Now, I have a lot of job titles that have the word "teacher" in it and I want to merge them.

For example!! teacher, teacher special ed, teacher per session, teacher general ed, and make just one category and store them under "teacher"!

That way when I look at **value_counts() for job title** I dont have many different teacher values, I just have 1 that includes all the different types of teachers into category "teacher".

Input

> df["job_title"].value_counts()

output:

> - teacher ....... 72979
> - teacher per session ...... 61369
> - teacher special ed ...... 24642

**I want my output as:**

> - teacher.......... (the sum of all 3 on top!)

Comment: I'm guessing I could do an .apply() where I go through the column and say if df["job_title].contains(teacher), change the actual job title to "teacher" .. and that way it is read as "teacher" and my value counts sees it as teacher and not unique teachers... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Series.str.contains()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to search for the matching string and then modify it as you wish:

```
df.loc[df['job_title'].str.contains('teacher'), 'job_title'] = 'teacher'
```

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'job_title': ['teacher', 'teacher per session', 'teacher special ed',
                      'programmer']
    }
)

print(df)
#             job_title
#0              teacher
#1  teacher per session
#2   teacher special ed
#3           programmer
```

Change all titles containing the word `'teacher'` to just `'teacher'`:

```
df.loc[df['job_title'].str.contains('teacher'), 'job_title'] = 'teacher'
print(df['job_title'].value_counts())
#teacher       3
#programmer    1
#Name: job_title, dtype: int64
```

Note that in this example, I am overwriting the existing column but you could just as easily create a new column:

```
df.loc[df['job_title'].str.contains('teacher'), 'new_job_title'] = 'teacher'
```

Comment: YES, THANK YOU! I was thinking this direction of a solution. 
I will let you know if it works.

Comment: Thank you, It worked perfectly! Just how I needed it to. I will use the bottom solution for when I need more specific merging. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can also create dictionary for job titles and replace the values in columns based on dictionary:

```
dictionary = {'teacher per session':'teacher', 'teacher special ed':'teacher'}
df['job_title'] = df.job_title.replace(dictionary)
```

Comment: This is also good because you can explicitly select which value to replace. One could imagine a scenario where a title is `'assistant to teacher'` that shouldn't be aggregated. My solution would not handle that case. The downside is that you have to enumerate all the possibilities.

Comment: Yes, this is a good solution! However, I used the one above, but I will keep this in mind as this would be helpful for other rows I might want to merge that are more vague and don't fit into 1 word! 

I agree with you Pault! This solution handles cases better. 

Thank you!